# Button loses its command binding after reordering it with drag drop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have created a `UserControl` that will bind to a list of dynamically created buttons on my view model and allow me to drag and drop reorder them.

After I drag a button to a new position in the list, the button I just dragged will no longer fire its command when clicked. If I move another button in the list, the first button now is able to be clicked and the one that was just dragged can not.

There are no binding errors in the command window.

The issue can be reproduced using the code below, and the following actions:

- put a break point on HandleContentButton() that will fire when a button
  is clicked
- Click button 1 and you will see it triggers the break point
- Drag button 1 over button 2 and they will switch places
- Click button 1 and nothing happens.
- Drag button 2 over button 3
- Now when you click button 1 it works but button 2 does not.

My control's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SafetyApplication.Controls.SortableItemsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SafetyApplication.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" IsTabStop="False" Name="icsp"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentButtons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="sp" AllowDrop="True" 
                                PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                                PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
                                PreviewMouseMove="sp_PreviewMouseMove"
                                DragEnter="sp_DragEnter" Drop="sp_Drop"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The control's code behind:

```
 public partial class SortableItemsControl : UserControl
    {
        #region Fields

        private bool _isDown;
        private bool _isDragging;
        private Point _startPoint;
        private UIElement _realDragSource;
        private readonly UIElement _dummyDragSource = new UIElement();

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public SortableItemsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Dependency Property

        #region Item Source

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(IEnumerable<UIElement>), typeof(SortableItemsControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemSourceChanged)));
        public IEnumerable<UIElement> ItemSource
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(ItemSourceProperty) as IEnumerable<UIElement>; }
            set { this.SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnItemSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sortableItemsControl = d as SortableItemsControl;
            if (sortableItemsControl?.ItemSource != null)
            {
                sortableItemsControl.icsp.ItemsSource = sortableItemsControl.ItemSource;
                sortableItemsControl.icsp.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Drag Drop Logic

        private void sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var sp = FindChild<StackPanel>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "sp");
            if (e.Source != sp)
            {
                _isDown = true;
                _startPoint = e.GetPosition(sp);
            }
        }

        private void sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDown = false;
            _isDragging = false;
            if (_realDragSource != null) _realDragSource.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void sp_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isDown)
            {
                var sp = FindChild<StackPanel>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "sp");
                if ((_isDragging == false) &&
                    ((Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(sp).X - _startPoint.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance) ||
                     (Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(sp).Y - _startPoint.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)))
                {
                    _isDragging = true;
                    _realDragSource = e.Source as UIElement;
                    if (_realDragSource != null) _realDragSource.CaptureMouse();
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dummyDragSource, new DataObject("UIElement", e.Source, true),
                        DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
            }
        }

        private void sp_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UIElement"))
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }

        private void sp_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("UIElement"))
            {
                var sp = FindChild<StackPanel>(this, "sp");
                UIElement droptarget = e.Source as UIElement;
                int droptargetIndex = -1, i = 0;
                foreach (UIElement element in sp.Children)
                {
                    if (element.Equals(droptarget))
                    {
                        droptargetIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (droptargetIndex != -1)
                {
                    var elements = icsp.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<UIElement>;
                    if (elements != null)
                    {
                        var items = elements.ToList();
                        UIElement button = _realDragSource;
                        items.Remove(button);
                        items.Insert(droptargetIndex, button);
                        icsp.ItemsSource = items;
                    }
                    icsp.Items.Refresh();
                }

                _isDown = false;
                _isDragging = false;
                _realDragSource.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Find Child

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
        /// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
        /// If not matching item can be found, 
        /// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
           where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

My view model:

```
 public class AdminViewModel
    {
        private readonly DataTransferManager _dataManager;

        public AdminViewModel(DataTransferManager dataManager)
        {
            _dataManager = dataManager;

            ContentButtonCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(HandleContentButton);

            BuildContentTable();
        }

        public ICommand ContentButtonCommand { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Button> ContentButtons { get; set; }

        private void HandleContentButton(object buttonDefinition)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        private void BuildContentTable()
        {
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Content = "Test 1";
            button1.Command = ContentButtonCommand;
            button1.CommandParameter = "Test 1";
            button1.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            buttons.Add(button1);

            Button button2 = new Button();
            button2.Content = "Test 2";
            button2.Command = ContentButtonCommand;
            button2.CommandParameter = "Test 2";
            button2.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            buttons.Add(button2);

            Button button3 = new Button();
            button3.Content = "Test 3";
            button3.Command = ContentButtonCommand;
            button3.CommandParameter = "Test 3";
            button3.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            buttons.Add(button3);


            ContentButtons = buttons;
        }

    }
```

A degenerate `RelayCommand<T>` implementation sufficient to support the above view model:

```
class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _handler;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

#pragma warning disable 0067
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
#pragma warning restore 0067

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _handler((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

and to use the control:

```
<controls:SortableItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding Path=ContentButtons}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks very much for the good code example. I only had to add `RelayCommand<T>` (see my edit above), and that's forgivable considering it's an implementation of such a commonly used pattern that it's easy to forget it's not actually in WPF. It is (sadly) all too rare to find a question so carefully presented, and it's very much appreciated.

As for your actual problem, there is a very easy fix. Set `_realDragSource` to `null` after actually doing the drop operation. E.g. as the last thing in your `sp_Drop()` method, just after you call `ReleaseMouseCapture()`, include this statement:

```
_realDragSource = null;
```

This fixes the problem in your code, in which if the user clicked on the button you had just dragged, your `sp_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp()` method would find the field non-null, and call `ReleaseMouseCapture()` during the handling of the mouse-button-up event. This had the consequence of causing the `Button` object itself to quit observing the mouse event just before it would have processed it.

In other words, your `Button` objects didn't lose their binding to the command (in fact you can inspect them in the debugger and see that their configuration never changes). They just ignored the user input that would have executed the command.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the issue here. You were right on.